# Cross-origin requests sent to Nginx are always pending

Tags: angularjs, nginx, cross-domain

Currently, my localhost is host on Nginx server in Vagrant.
 
The backend is coded in Laravel framework. In order to make it to support cross-origin requests, I have added CORS Provider to config/app.php. 
This is the git page for CORS: 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors 
The screenshot is config/app.php for CORS:
[image]

The screenshot is config/cors.php
[image]
The front end is implemented in AngularJS, call back-end Api by $http. 
By monitoring the network on Chrome: 
[image]
Go to AngularJS library
[image]

This only happens once a while, and it happens to production server as well. 
The screenshot is from production server: 
[image]

I can't figure out why since it doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: Help, please~ I don't think this problem is related to code, maybe it is the configuration of the server. If more information need to be known, I am happy to provide it. Many thanks.

Comment: Anyone? Help please...